# Why does the Catholic Church teach that Noah's ark was "complete in one cubit"?

Tags: catholicism, latin, ark-of-noah, papal-bull

According to Pope Boniface VIII's bull *[Unam sanctam](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/bon08/b8unam.htm)* (1302),

> Indeed, at the time of the flood there was one ark of Noah, prefiguring the one Church, **made complete in one cubit** [*Una nempe fuit diluvii tempore arca Noe, unam Ecclesiam praefigurans, quae **in uno cubito consummata***] (Denzinger-Hünermann 870)

What does it mean that the arc was "made complete in one cubit"?

Comment: I added a link to one version of Unam sanctam, but the translation is a bit different. Is the quote in OP your translation or someone else's (can you provide a source)? Does the linked text give a different meaning that changes your understanding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that it was made perfectly, according to God's specifications / will.

"*In uno cubito [consummata](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=consummata#lexicon)*" means accomplished/completed/finished/perfected exactly, to a single cubit, "[to a tee](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/196711#eid19408419)."

Comment: The absence of the article in Latin causes ambiguities of language. 'Fasihioned to the cubit' is how both Greek and English might say it. Latin has to bring in a number, which then becomes a problem.

Comment: Was there no smaller unit? 'Perfect to half-a-metre' does not sound impressive

Comment: @bukwyrm it was specified to the cubit. So perfect to the specifications sounds good to me.

Comment: @bukwyrm It would have been pretty impressive with the technology of the day.